# Send data from Python to Javascript (JSON)

Tags: javascript, python, json

I know JSON to solve this problem, but I have problems in implementing it. Here is the detail of my approach:

1. Data are calculated in Python
2. Since the size of data is dynamic, so I need to use JavaScript to create extra HTML table rows for my outputs. As a result, I need to pass data from Python to JavaScript to let Javascript to 'see' the data.

HTML Code (below is a section of my HTML code to create the output page):

```
class OutputPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def func (a,b):
        return a+b #just an example

    def get(self):
        form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
        chem_name = form.getvalue('chemical_name')
        Para1 = form.getvalue('Para1')  #get values from input page--user inputs
        Para1 = float(Para1)
        Para2 = form.getvalue('Para2')  #get values from input page--user inputs
        Para2 = float(Para2)
        out = func (Para1,Para1)
        out_json=simplejson.dumps(out)  # I need to send out to JavaScript
        #writ output page
        templatepath = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../templates/'
        html = html + template.render (templatepath + 'outputpage_start.html', {})
        html = html + template.render (templatepath + 'outputpage_js.html', {})               
        html = html + """<table width="500" class='out', border="1">
                          <tr>  
                            <td>parameter 1</td>
                            <td>&nbsp</td>                            
                            <td>%s</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>  
                            <td>parameter 2</td>
                            <td>&nbsp</td>                            
                            <td>%s</td>
                          </tr>                                                      
                          </table><br>"""%(Para1, Para2)
        html = html + template.render(templatepath + 'outputpage_end.html', {})
        #attempt to 'send' Python data (out_json) to JavaScript, but I failed.
        html = html + template.render({"my_data": out_json})  
        self.response.out.write(html)

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', OutputPage)], debug=True)
```

JavaScript Code (I use JavaScript to create additional inputs tables on the fly filename:'outputpage_js.html'):

```
<script>
<script type='text/javascript'> 

$(document).ready(function(){
    //I assume if my Json statement works, I should be able to use the following argument to create a HTML row
    $('<tr><td>Parameter 2</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>out_json</td>').appendTo('.app')   

</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you explain, why exactly are you trying to pass data in the same template that will then generate HTML code? I do not see any dynamic loading (like AJAX) in your question, only not necessary JavaScript code that will generate part of the template you were not able to generate using Python. Am I correct?

Comment: @Tadeck, the reason to use JavaScript is because I need to use JavaScript to create html tables. Plus, the size of my data is dynamic. So I think it is better to use JSON to pass data to JavaScript and let it to handle it. In addition, I also need to use Jqplot to generate figures. Currently, I generate all the values in a hidden html table and let JavaScript to get them by selecting id names. But I think there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: @Tao, is the data dynamicly updating? Meaning will the user see data change on the fly without a page refresh? If it's dynamic, you would need AJAX code to request the JSON data from a URL that only returns JSON (no HTML). If the data is known when the page is loaded, then you just need to add the JavaScript data structure to your page template. No JSON or AJAX required.

Comment: @jiggy, I guess my case belongs to the second category. I need to use JavaScript to create some html rows and use Jqplot to create plots. But my question is, how could I 'tell' JavaScript parameters created in Python?

Comment: @tao.hong: You do not need JavaScript, nor AJAX, if the data you want to display is dynamic. This is because you are already dynamically generating the HTML (see your code). So just generate your HTML from the beginning, fully in Python. The things begin to change when you need the data in the JavaScript for the purposes you mentioned (using in the script, eg. for diagramming). **This** is the reason for passing JSON. To do that, you can simply generate JSON in Python (`simplejson.dumps(some_data)`), and place it within HTML's `data-` attributes (eg. in `data-parameters`) properly escaped.

Comment: @Tadeck, thanks for the suggestion. I think data-parameters could be the approach I am looking for. Could you please give me an example of using data-parameters to expose JSON data into an HTML? Thanks!

Comment: @tao.hong: Of course, there are plenty of examples: [by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), [by W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), [in jQuery documentation of jQuery's `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) and [plenty of other resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+data+attribute+example).

Comment: @Tadeck, one quick question. What is the benefit of using data- attributes versus generate a html table and hide those data. Thanks!

Comment: @tao.hong: semantics. If you do not want HTML, then why generate it in the first place? Second, if you have it not in JSON, then parsing it requires walking through the DOM elements and retrieving this data (which is not very efficient). Third, the simplicity (eg. using jQuery.data() you already have the data parsed, no need to parse it yourself, which would not be really DRY and would be error-prone).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you don't have to "implement" JSON, python comes with a built in lib, called `simplejson`, which you can feed with normal dicts:

```
try: 
  import simplejson as json
except:
  import json
out = {'key': 'value', 'key2': 4}
print json.dumps(out)
```

**EDIT:**
as tadeck pointed out, simplejson *should* be more up-to-date and is not equal to json, but there is a chance, simplejson is not available due to it is maintained externaly

**EDIT 2:**
based on the discussion in this answer and the discussion on the page, i think, the best approach would be something like that:

*python*

```
# [...] generate dynamic data [...]
html = html + template.render (templatepath + 'outputpage_start.html', {})
html = html + template.render (templatepath + 'outputpage_js.html', {})               
html = html + """<table width="500" class='out' border="1" data-dynamic="%s">""" % json.dumps(your_generated_data_dict)
#tr/td elements and templating as needet
self.response.out.write(html)
```

*javascript*

```
$(function(){
    var your_generated_table = $('table'),
        dynamic_data = JSON.parse(your_generated_table.attr('data-dynamic'));
});
```

you then have the exact same structure your python dict has as a javascript object.

Comment: The library is just `json` in python2.6 and up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you give me a hint on how to combine json.dumps into my case (do I need to render it? Since I need to let JavaScript to see it)?

Comment: @MikeSteder: No, `simplejson` is not `json`. `simplejson` is externally maintained version of `json` module, with various advantages, eg. it is more up-to-date and faster (according to `simplejson`'s page). I would really suggest using `simplejson` with fallback to `json`, if `simplejson` has not been found (you know: `try: import simplejson as json; except ImportError: import json`). You can find it here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/

Comment: i am not quite sure about your framework, but you can treat json like normal output. Best way is to retrieve it via a JS Framework like JQuery. If this is static content, you can put it within a data-* attribute and read it with JS or put the JSON directly into a javascript tag, assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @DesertEagle: Is there any example for your approaches? I am really not quite familiar with JSON.

Comment: @tao.hong: based on the discussions here i edited the answer, hope that helps

Comment: To be precise, Json is just a mapping (string-based). If you return `{'result': 'this is result'}` and on the client side you have `$.ajax` and waiting for `response`, then you can access it as `response.result`

Comment: @User007: Not really. What you have given as example is not correct JSON (try to parse it eg. using simplejson and you will see it for yourself). Second, jQuery is pretty intelligent, but you need to pass it correct data type ("json") so it knows how to parse the response. Third, best practice for accessing properties is to use square brackets and quotation marks instead of dots (you have higher flexibility and consistency that way, plus you can use variables for properties' names).