# How to send data from Python script to JavaScript and vice-versa?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am trying to make a calculator (with matrix calculation also). I want to make interface in JavaScript and calculation stuff in Python. But I don't know how to send parameters from python to JavaScript and from JavaScript to python.

Edit: I want to send data via JSON (if possible).

Comment: are you writing an application which has Javascript on the interface and the backend is written in Python? If yes, what framework are you using ?

Comment: Is this answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959895/send-data-from-python-to-javascript-json

Comment: @KeZhu Yes, python as a backend and JS as a frontend. I am using Flask. I am hoping to transfer data as JSON but don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript, you need to make a AJAX call to your server where your python is running. A package like axio will make things much easier:

The following javascript will invoke the RESTAPI and perform according to the response

```
var promise = axios.create({ baseURL: "https://yourhost/rootpath/", timeout: 100000 }).get("path/to/rest")
promise.then((response) = > {... do something ...})
```

On your Flask application, you define a function which is attached to your specified RESTApi Paht like this:

```
@app.route('path/to/rest', methods=['GET'])
def do_something():
    return {"result" : "value" }
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to essentially set both of them up as API's and access them via endpoints.

For Javascript, you can use node to set up your API endpoint, and for Python use Flask.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I don't want to use API specifically. Is there any way I can use JSON??

Comment: API and JSON are two completely different things. There's no way for you to grab data from Javascript to Python without having a server or a means for those two scripts to communicate with each other. JSON is just a data structure.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about displaying on a webpage? You will need to have some web framework like flask, django etc to process the web page request, then render the html.

Typically, when you render the html, you can generate json objects so your javascript can read.

Alternatively your javascript will make an ajax call to the server so that you python can return json response.

I've used https://cherrypy.org/ to implement some APIs, you don't need heavy frameworks like Django if you are only displaying a simple page.

Comment: How do I make an AJAX call? Would you link some tutorial or reference? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you would want to create a  [server with Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html) in which your JavaScript [makes AJAX calls to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) endpoints that you create with your Python server.

In your calculator example, you would send the parameters of the calculation to the server (lets say /calculate endpoint). The server would make the calculation, and would return the value back to the JavaScript front end for it to display.